# Class extended method should return the extended classes type instead of the base classes without redefining the function in the extended class

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
class Base<TModules extends string> {
  addModule<TModuleName extends string>(
    this: Base<TModules>,
    name: TModuleName
  ): Base<TModules | TModuleName> {
    // Type cast the current instance to include the new generic type
    return this as Base<TModules | TModuleName>;
  }

  getModule<TModuleName extends TModules>(name: TModuleName) {
    // Implementation of getModule method goes here
  }

  // ...additional methods
}

class BaseExtension<TModules extends string> extends Base<TModules> {
  // ... some functions here
}

// Example usage:
const baseInstance = new Base<"ModuleA">();
const extendedInstance = new BaseExtension<"ModuleA">();

const newBaseInstance = baseInstance.addModule("ModuleB"); // newBaseInstance will have type: Base<"ModuleA" | "ModuleB">
const newExtendedInstance = extendedInstance.addModule("ModuleC"); // newExtendedInstance should have the type: BaseExtension<"ModuleA" | "ModuleC"> but instead it has the type Base<"ModuleA" | "ModuleC">
```

What I would like to achieve, is to be able to define extended classes for the `Base` class, on which after calling the `addModule` method, the return type should be the extended classes type, with modified generic values.

I know that I could redefine the functions in `BaseExtension` to overwrite the return type to be a `BaseExtension` class, but this would introduce a bunch of other overhead issues that is not viable for my exact use cause. Isn't there an easier way that could achieve the same result without the need to modify each class that extends my Base class?

Here's [a fiddle on ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAsgewCYFcQJgQA8AXBAOyxghICcBLcgcwD5oBvAKGmjCy0y58qQXgQA5MAFsE0YmUrU6jVgApuPaCQAW9CAC44iEdjEQWAGg09y0hIfSn8kmRoCUh%20BGSOhBaAA%200L5iLghsXJrQAPTRwQCeAA6ywJAkWtopOLS0FOmMNGDkwLIkGNCMoDhYpZnQ5AgA7tBMFAgMwFpJCNbQuSTZ5Bl6vDBePqL4MEEhznYsANwaAL6cGq0kkxNOEnZypBRUwVvmqrYyDlthbhy9sdAAklKJ%20DLkJGAk9BhDGABmLQQmx20BkOmwLQw-kyuRWax49wAdMi%20Fh6F8fmAQKCgdpsBBOKtOKBIGNEABRA7kCDfcgmPyEKlHGgMZhseSHMneelmCIaJHI6AQDAyaB-HDFDHU6AwnpE%206U6QvWQ4CBgVr6Yk-GjQABGiAe1I%20xVkAF56k0jNyAERbACC1pYqjcS2A2vSHMoCCwhsKJug5oazXGlIUNJ%20SFtOwdTpdazdRotjXGvuNJQDeoNRqKJURqK2qijflg1pdMTiQZT2f9jXoIGx2jAADdSt1PMYi2IHYFoJ38CWWFrE0HQ4dvamc2b9goaj7q7n8ztC1sAMKlhblpOjr1zv3piB4vBYGXN2qt5Lt7zb8N0vsIbtBO9rti6nD5I0IPgVdKNmA6c%20yOMkb2taPZPo6azRAAVFBjzQAA1uQGDNDonxwW6R59N6CB-IwZ5ihKwBSjAjBWgg160lo5QYC2tCNAwZAZLI-SDF0yRUXqshgGRFE-NAJJQBYepvtA3CwRUEDkAA5Ok-65LwQyfjS7TQI0YDxBkaEYSAx5gMAugIC2TFCnsuQQHg6S1uCIn-ha3ocVI2D0H8Gmfvp-HgFAmkekyMBSBp4weaSAD80BQdEQA)

Comment: Without direct support for higher kinded types as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), this is impossible (or at least more cumbersome than the workaround you describe as "not viable"). See [ms/TS#6223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6223) for specifics.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?